# SSHD Deny/allow access by ip for group

Tags: ssh, redhat

I have a RHEL 7 server, and I need to setup SSH access based on group and IPs. Basically I have two group of users (sshusers and exchangefiles). Users of the first group should be allowed access from any IP, except a specific one. Users of the second group should only be allowed access from that specific IP. I've seen that you can do that with AllowUsers muyser@1.1.1.1, but the same thing does not seem to with AllowGroups exchangefiles@1.1.1.1. Is there any way to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make use of a `Match` blocks in `sshd_config`

```
Match Address 192.0.2.1
    DenyGroups Group1
Match Address *,!192.0.2.1
    DenyGroups Group2
```

---

Caution should be used if instead making use of `AllowGroups`. `DenyGroups` is a blacklist. `AllowGroups` is a mandatory whitelist.